# javascript callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function make(callback) {
    //some other manipulation to get data to pass it into $.post()
    $.post(data, function(response) {
        // do something
        callback()
    });
}

function two() {
    make(function() {
        console.log('hello');
    });
}
```

`console.log('hello')` will still trigger first although I used callback. How to make make() run till everything is finished then trigger `console.log('hello')`?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with above above pseudo-code, `console.log('hello')` should execute at end. You must be doing something else.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work as soon as you call `two()`.

This might visualize your situation better:

```
function requestSomething(callback) {
    $.post(data, function(response) {
        // do something
        callback();
    });
}

function callBackFunction() {
    console.log('done!');
}

// Pass callBackFunction, which gets called after request.
requestSomething(callBackFunction);
```